# How to analyze time series data with only 20 data points?

Tags: time-series, small-sample

I have a set of times series data on the annual growth in GDP of East Asia's 20 biggest cities over the time period of 1981-2016. I am trying to find out:

1. Whether or not Hong Kong's GDP data fits with the overall trend of these 20 cities or if it is statistically significantly different
2. Whether there is a structural break in Hong Kong's data (specifically testing for if the pre-1997 GDP data fits with the rest of the cities, while post-1997 data does not).

I am confused about how to approach this analysis on stata. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!